# Maintaining Javascript functionality in dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic-content, sorttable.js

I'm looking for a quality mechanism to add sorting to dynamically generated tables. My visual setup is very simple. On the left side I have a menu with series of items to select from (charts, graphs, images, tables, etc.). Once an item is clicked, it will show up in the "dynamic-content" div on the right side of the page. That all works fine.

What I'm having issue with is being able to implement certain dynamic features of the loaded content. In this particular case, I have dynamic content that gets generated based on the table that is selected and it appears in the "dynamic-content" div, but the JavaScript sorting doesn't work. I've tried including it in the "Application Layout" page as well as in the partial that generates the data, but nothing works. However, if I put it in a "static" page all works fine. Any ideas on how to get this working?

FYI I'm using Rails 2.3.4 on OS X, using "sorttable.js", and Safari 4.0.3 & Firefox 3.5.5 to test.

Comment: Would you be open to using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that you need to call `sorttable.makeSortable(<table element>);` on your dynamically loaded tables. Since you didn't provide any background on how you're switching out your tables, it's hard to provide a solution.

Sorttable.js relies on [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), the tables to be sortable must be present in the dom when the page is finished loading. Sorttable.js then calls makeSortable on each table that has the "sortable" class. When you insert your new table, you need to do the same.

Comment: Yes, I believe that *is* the issue -- which is why I tried adding it to the dynamically loaded content so that it would always be present in real-time with the new content, but that seems to fail.  Can you recommend any other solutions that don't involve me re-submitting back to the server to retrieve the old data in a new order?  I'd like to keep it sleek, but at this point, I'm up for whatever.

Comment: Have you tried manually calling makeSortable after you generate your data?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to get this working?

Well without more info it'll be hard to come up with a solution. But have you tried looking at the generated page with Firebug to see what's going on? Does your IDE have a Javascript debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried debugging in both Safari and Firefox and nothing appears to be firing.  I think it is as flyfishr64 says -- all data is required to be present up front, which, unfortunately, can't happen in this case.